# Unitywebrequest cannot upload file via APK

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file in Unity using `Unitywebrequest.post` via API in my Android application. When the app is running on emulator, the upload is working fine, but when I generate an APK, and install it on my Android device, the upload does not work and the file was not sent to the destination URL. Why is that?

This is the code I'm using

```
File.writeAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../" + timestamp + ".jpeg",bytes); 
WWWForm from = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("token", tokenlogin.text);
form.AddBinaryData("image",bytes,timestamp + ".jpeg");
UnityWebRequest w = UnityWebRequest.Post("EndpointAddress",form);
yield return w.SendWebRequest();
```

Comment: Not entirely sure if needed but...have you write permisions?

Comment: Do you get any errors? You might already get an exception when `File.WriteAllBytes` so it never reaches the web request. Rather use `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, timestamp + ".jpeg")` ... it automatically fills in the correct path separators `/` or `\` according to the OS .. also not sure if `..` is valid here ... you should rather store **into** the `Application.persistentDataPath` .. why are you trying to store something above it?

Comment: Welcome! Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help asking a better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `/../` so basically trying to write your file one folder **above** the application's data path.

Usually on Android applications are sandboxed to their own according application data so you might get an **exception** due to not having the **permissions** to write here when doing

```
File.WriteAllBytes
```

so it never even reaches the web request.

Also note that there is a difference between [`dataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html)

> Contains the path to the game data folder on the target device
>
> [...]
>
> **Android**: Normally it points directly to the APK. If you are running a split binary build, it points to the OBB instead.

and [`persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

> This value is a directory path where you can store data that you want to be kept between runs. When you publish on iOS and Android, `persistentDataPath` points to a public directory on the device. Files in this location are not erased by app updates.

So as I understand it the [`dataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) means the installation folder while `pesristentDataPath` is a dedicated folder where an application stores its runtime data.

---

You should rather write your file using something like

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // in the Unity Editor write to streaming assets instead of "somewhere"
    // hidden in the %AppData% on your system
    var folder = Application.streamingAssetsPath;
    if(!Directory.Exists(folder))
    {
        Directory.Create(folder);
    }
#else
    var folder = Application.persistentDataPath;
#endif

var filePath = Path.Combine(folder, timestamp + ".jpeg");
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
```

so writing **into** the [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) (or the [`StreamingAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) folder in the UnityEditor)